# Loop iterating only through half of the elements

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, srand

Here is my code. My question is, why does it keep printing only 5 numbers? Why won't it print 10 like it's supposed to?

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   #include<time.h>

   int main(){

   int r, col;

   srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

   for (col=1; col<=10; col++){

   r = rand() % 11;
   printf("%d\n", r);
   col++;

   }
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: omit the `col++;` inside the loop or just modify this line `for (col=1; col<=10; col++)` to `for (col=1; col<=10; )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, you are doing `col++` **twice**, once in the loop body, and once in the post-loop statement.

```
for (col=1; col<=10; col++)   //...................(i)
                    ^^^^^^^
```

and

```
r = rand() % 11;
printf("%d\n", r);
col++;                       //.....................(ii)
^^^^^
```

So, for a single iteration, `col` gets incremented *twice*, iteration count gets halved.

Remove either of the statements.

Comment: Thanks mate and excuse me for this noob question and the other noob questions to come

Answer (score 0):

You have made a mistake - you don't need to write the `col++` twice!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(){

    int r, col;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    for (col=1; col<=10; col++){

        r = rand() % 11;
        printf("%d\n", r);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Double col++. "for" loop statement include three expressions.
First is called once at beginning. Usually used for counter initialization.
Second is loop continue condition check. Called before every iteration. If result of expression false loop will be stopped.
Third part called after every iteration. Usually used for counter increment.

If you used col++ in the "for" and want "col" to be incremented by 1 every iteration you don't execute col++ in the loop body.

```
#include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   #include<time.h>

   int main(){

   int r, col;

   srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

   for (col=1; col<=10; col++){

   r = rand() % 11;
   printf("%d\n", r);
   //col++;

   }
  return 0;
  }
```